# about liked list, how can I push front Nth numbers that randomly created?

Tags: c++, linked-list, insert

I have a question about linked list c++.
    I know how to insert front one data, but I want to insert front multiple numbers that randomly created.
    This is my push_front() function. I need to use this function to implement push_frontN() function.
    please help me!!

```
struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node(int i = 0; Node* n = nullptr){
        data = i, next = n;
    }
    ~Node() {}
};

int size(Node* p) {
    if (empty(p)) return 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (pNode c = p; c != nullptr; c = c->next, count++);
    return count;
}

Node* push_front(Node* p, int val){
    if(empty(p)) return new Node{val}; //function empty is already created.
    return new Node{val, p};
}

unsigned long rand_extended(int range) {
    if (range < RAND_MAX) return rand();
    return rand() * RAND_MAX + rand();
}

Node* push_frontN(Node* p, int N){
    int range = N + size(p);  

    srand((unsigned)time(nullptr));  

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int val = rand() % range;
        p = push_front(p, val);
        cout << setw(7) << "\r\tinserting in [" << i << "]=" << val;
    }
    cout << "\n";

    return p;
}  

Thank you
```

Comment: You need to write a loop that calls push_front N times. That maybe obvious to you, so have a go yourself, and if it doesn't work post your attempt at the solution here for suggestions. Don't expect anyone to write the code for you. You will learn more by trying to write the code yourself, even if you aren't successful.

Comment: You could even make things easier for yourself. Instead of trying to push random numbers, try to push the same number N times. And then when you have that worked out, modify your code to push the random numbers.

Comment: okay, I have tried this before, but it didn't work, this is what I did,

pNode push_frontN(pNode p, int N) {

 int range = N + size(p);
 srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
 for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  int val = rand() % range;
  p = push_front(p, val);
  cout << setw(7) << "\r\tinserting in [" << i << "]=" << val;
 }
 cout << "\n";

 return p;
}

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable, edit the question and put the code there.

Comment: sorry, this is my first experience to post here, 
I edited my codes

Comment: Your code looks OK to me. Please don't say 'it doesn't work', describe what actually happens when you run this code.

Comment: I know right? I don't see any problems too, but when I run this code, it doesn't push any numbers

Comment: Well I'm 99% sure the code is right, it's more likely that the bug is in the code you are using to test this code. But since I can't see that code I'm only speculating. Maybe you forgot to assign the return value from push_frontN to a variable so you could print out the new list.

Comment: okay, I will check if Im missing something. Thank you so much.
I will let you know if I have other questions.